# How to implement file upload along with some form data, using Java EE 7 specs?

Tags: file-upload, java-ee-7

Currently I am using org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput for file upload. I want to replace it with some generic Java EE design. Please suggest possible ways to upload file along with few other form data using Java EE 7 specs.

Comment: I tend to handle file uploads with a regular Servlet myself, still. The servlet 3.0 spec (since JEE6) has added multipart handling support out of the box. Is that within the scope of the question or must it be JAX-RS based?

Comment: What we are trying to do is, we are trying to get the file information from the request without using any third party api's. Does you code/implementation do that? If yes, can you please share your code/idea ?

Comment: I take that as a yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score -1):

The Java EE 7 has focused on RESTful webservices. So to do something corresponding the specs' approach, keep using JAX-RS 2.0 API:

Here you want to want to upload a file to your app => you want to POST a FILE to your JAX-RS Service. Your method can be like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    //Your local disk path where you want to store the file
    String uploadedFileLocation = "D://uploadedFiles/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
    System.out.println(uploadedFileLocation);
    // save it
    File  objFile=new File(uploadedFileLocation);
    if(objFile.exists())
    {
        objFile.delete();
    }

    try {
        OutputStream out = null;
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String output = "File uploaded via JAX-RS based RESTFul Webservice to: " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

This a Java EE 7 compliant Upload File JAX-RS Service.

Comment: @FormDataParam is available inside jersey-multipart-api and hence is a third party implementation, I want an implementation based on JAX-RS, using javax.ws api's. Is there any generic spec compliant to both resteasy and jersey?

Comment: Jersey framework is the JAX-RS Reference Implementation. Resteasy is an other implementation of JAX-RS.
Resteasy is not handling the MultiPartData differently : http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html#MultipartFormData
If you want to do "portable" code between Jersey & Resteasy, I think this is not possible actually.

Comment: @JsonBourne Thats's exactly what I want, I want a code independent of the implementer, code that should run with both RestEasy and Jersey. Portable code as you rightly pointed out.